# css to apply only in template area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an input in my website which allows the user to write an html email template. Basically I use codemirror (just the one I found online and working). In that template the user can write css too. The template is saved okay.

The issue is when I try to display the template in a preview for the user. Everything loads okay (html and styles) but the styles apply to my whole website not only in the template part.

Is there a way to limit the area or something of the css from the blob variable(html email template) ? Any other suggestion is welcome.

> one logical solution is to have different styles form the ones of the users template, but I guess I cant limit the users input styles

EDIT

I have this textarea:

```
<textarea name="email_template" id="email_template"></textarea>
```

an example of user input:

```
.body div{
            /*@editable*/ color:#505050;
            /*@editable*/ font-family:Arial;
            /*@editable*/ font-size:14px;
            /*@editable*/ line-height:150%;
            /*@editable*/ text-align:left;
        }

<div class='bodyContent '> Hello Guys this is an email template </div>
```

then the input is saved as a BLOB in a database.

The problem: When the I display the input to a div with javascript:

> emailTemplate is just another div to load the content of the BlOB

```
document.getElementById("emailTemplate").innerHTML = data[0]['email_template'];
```

if I have a class `body` outside of that `emailTemplate` gets affected too.

Comment: Why can't you add a id or class to the template and make sure the css rules are specific for that class/id?

Comment: Use a class or ID to identify your template area and place all your specific CSS under this class or ID. Like `.template-area label { color: red; }` meaning all labels inside template area.

Comment: the template is saved with the styles and html as one in a blob form the user. i cant control the input. classes and ids can be anything the user likes

Comment: if these 2 comments do not solve your problem, please share some code to clarify your intent.

Comment: 2 possibilities: 1) parse the user input and change it (maybe just on display) - ie change their css so that it targets your input.   2) display the user content in an `iframe` - that way it won't "leak" into your main page.

Comment: omg thank you so much @freedomn-m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `<iframe>` instead of a `<div>`to display the user content, so it wont apply to the whole document.

Because the document in the iframe is a different webpage for the browser, anything like css declarations, or javascript global functions will work only inside the `<iframe>`